# how to loop throught csv file with post request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a post request which looks like this
{ "action": "CN", "contract": "138484833", "company": "B", "job_number": 1234564, "timestamp": 2020121710470000 }
similarly I have 10 rows with above request only the values changes, I need to loop through all the ten record from csv and execute it in Jmeter.

I tried using Beanshell preprocessor, is there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a CSV file which looks like:

[image]

Textual representation:

```
action,contract,company,job_number,timestamp
CN,138484833,B,1234564,2020121710470000
DN,138484834,C,1234565,2020121710480000
EN,138484835,D,1234566,2020121710490000
```

You can build your request using the data from the file as follows:

1. Add [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) as a child of the request you want to parameterize
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image]
3. In the "Body data" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler use the following syntax:

   ```
   {
     "action": "${action}",
     "contract": "${contract}",
     "company": "${company}",
     "job_number": ${job_number},
     "timestamp": ${timestamp}
   }
   ```

   [image]
4. That's it, each virtual user will read the next row from the CSV file on each iteration and substitute [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) placeholders with the real values from the CSV file

   [image]

Comment: It only executes the first record of the csv file. and moreover i also need to know how can i dynamically change the value of my variable which should take the value from the resultant variable.

Comment: Thank you, I added ${__javaScript("${var1}"!="",)} in while controller and defined var1 in csv config it worked.